# Does Firefox implements SCSV?

Tags: tls, firefox, cipher-selection, ciphers

I need to know if Mozilla Firfox implements the [SCSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7507) which adds a specific ciphersuite in case if the client initial hello message is resent (either due to MITM or due to network erro).

I opened about:config and checked the supported ciphersuites. I can not find the SCSV cipher. Why Firefox does not implement this protection mechanism? Are you aware of any brosers that do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCSV is not a real cipher but only a pseudo-cipher, i.e. a hack to notify that the client currently does a TLS fallback. And because it is not a real cipher there is no way to enable or disable it as cipher.

Comment: Thanks. Then, how can I check whether Firefox implements it or not?

Comment: @user6875880: according to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94848/how-much-protection-is-really-offered-by-tls-fallback-scsv Firefox should support it. But to try yourself you need to make TLS 1.2 to fail (maybe with a custom server) so that you can watch a downgrade to TLS 1.0 with tcpdump or wireshark.